# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de los select que he seleccionado?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

quiero obtener el resultado de los select que yo seleccione me los imprima en otro php y si me lo hace pero en ves que me imprima el nombre me imprime el id que tiene dicho nombre en la base de datos, qui les dejo mi codigo por partes, espero me explique bien y puedan ayudarme soy nuevo en lo laboral y es parte de mi primer proyecto.

```
<?php
require ('conexion.php');

$query = "SELECT id_marca, nom_marca FROM marcas ORDER BY nom_marca";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Y DESPUES MI SELECT

```
<form id="combo" action="index-details.php" method="POST">
    
        <select class="form-select" name="select_marca" id="cbx_marca">
        <option value="0">MARCA: </option>
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id_marca']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nom_marca']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>

        <select class="form-select" name="select_modelo" id="cbx_modelo">
        <option value="0">MODELO: </option>
        </select>
        

        <select class="form-select" name="select_anio" id="cbx_año">
        <option value="0">AÑO: </option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-select" name="select_linea" id="cbx_linea">
        <option  value="0">LINEA: </option>
        </select>
        
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="boton-neon" id="submit" name="submit" 
        style="color: #2C3E50;">BUSCAR PRODUCTO</button>
    </form>
```

DESPUES CON JAVASCRIPT LOS MUESTRO EN CADA SELECT

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {
                
                $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_marca = $(this).val();
                    $.post("includes/getModelo.php", { id_marca: id_marca }, function(data){
                        $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_modelo").change(function () {
                $("#cbx_modelo option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_modelo = $(this).val();
                    $.post("includes/getAnio.php", { id_modelo: id_modelo }, function(data){
                        $("#cbx_año").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_año").change(function () {
                $("#cbx_año option:selected").each(function () {
                    id_año = $(this).val();
                    $.post("includes/getLinea.php", { id_año: id_año }, function(data){
                        $("#cbx_linea").html(data);
                    });            
                });
            })
        });
</script
```

DESPUES TENGO TRES PHP DISTINTOS UNO CON GETMODELO.PHP QUE MANDO A LLAMAR MI TABLA MODELOS DONDE SE MOSTRARA EN MI SELECT MODELO

```
<?php
require ('../conexion.php');

$id_marca = $_POST['id_marca'];

$queryM = "SELECT id_modelo, nom_modelo FROM modelos WHERE id_marca = '
$id_marca' ORDER BY nom_modelo ASC";
$resultadoM = $mysqli->query($queryM);

$html= "<option>Selecciona el Modelo</option>";

while($rowM = $resultadoM->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$rowM['id_modelo']."'>".$rowM['nom_modelo'].
    "</option>";
}

echo $html;
?>
```

DESPUES TENGO MI OTRA TABLA LLAMADA GETANIO(AÑO) QUE MANDARE PARA MOSTRAR EN EL SELECT

```
<?php
require ('../conexion.php');

$id_modelo = $_POST['id_modelo'];

$query = "SELECT id_año, num_año FROM año WHERE id_modelo = '$id_modelo' ORDER BY num_año";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

$html= "<option value='0'>Selecciona el Año</option>";

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$row['id_año']."'>".$row['num_año']."</option>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

Y POR ULTIMO GETLINEA.PHP PARA MANDAR A LLENAR MI SELECT EN MI SELECT LINEA

```
<?php
require ('../conexion.php');

$id_año = $_POST['id_año'];

$query = "SELECT id_linea, nom_linea FROM linea WHERE id_año = '$id_año' ORDER BY nom_linea";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

$html= "<option value='0'>Selecciona la Linea</option>";

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
{
    $html.= "<option value='".$row['id_linea']."'>".$row['nom_linea']."</option>";
}
echo $html;
?>
```

ESO ES TODO Y YA CUANDO QUIERO OBTENER EL RESULTADO QUE YO ELIGA DE LOS 4 SELECT DEPENDIENTES ME DE EL RESULTADO LO HACE PERO ME ENSEÑA PRO NUMERO QUE SON LOS ID DE SU COUMNA EN LA BASE DE DATOS, Y DE ESTA MANERA MANDO A LLAMARLOS PARA QUE ME LOS MUESTRE EN MI OTRO PHP LLAMADO INDEX-DETAILS.PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["select_linea"])){$select_linea=$_POST["select_linea"];}
?>
```

AHI SOLO IMPRIMO LINEA QUE ME LA MUESTRE YA CAMBIARIA EL SELECT_LINEA A MARCA O MODELO DEPENDIENDO.
ESPERO PUEDAN AYUDARME.

Comment: este es mi javascript en el index para que mi select dependa de uno sobre el otro

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cbx_marca").change(function () {
     
     $("#cbx_marca option:selected").each(function () {
      id_marca = $(this).val();
      $.post("includes/getModelo.php", { id_marca: id_marca }, function(data){
       $("#cbx_modelo").html(data);
      });            
     });
    })
   });

Comment: mi error es en el option value, imprimo con echo id y nombre pero al obtenerlo con popst me sale el id

Comment: este es el error 
$html.= "<option value='".$rowM['id_modelo']."'>".$rowM['nom_modelo']."</option>";

pero si hago esto si me sale el resultado pero ya no hay dependencia del segundo select se pierte por completo

$html.= "<option value='".$rowM['nom_modelo']."'>".$rowM['nom_modelo']."</option>";

Comment: este es mi select 

<select class="form-select" name="select_marca" id="cbx_marca">
   <option value="0">MARCA: </option>
   <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id_marca']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nom_marca']; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>

y al obtener con post asi lo tengo

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["select_marca"])){$select_marca=$_POST["select_marca"];}
    ?>
    <div style="padding:20px;"><?php echo "MARCA: ".$select_marca."";?></div>

pero obtengo el id_marca en ves del nom_marca.

Comment: listo lo edite la publicacion